# How to rollback a database transaction when testing services with Spring in JUnit?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, transactions, junit

I have no problem testing my DAO and services, but when I test `INSERT`s or `UPDATE`s I want to rollback the transaction and not effect my database.

I'm using `@Transactional` inside my services to manage transactions. I want to know, is it possible to know if a transaction will be fine, but rollback it to prevent altering database?

This is my Test:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = "classpath:/META-INF/spring.cfg.xml")
@TransactionConfiguration(defaultRollback=true)
public class MyServiceTest extends AbstractJUnit38SpringContextTests  {
    @Autowired
    private MyService myService;

    @BeforeClass
    public static void setUpClass() throws Exception {
    }

    @AfterClass
    public static void tearDownClass() throws Exception {
    }

    @Test
    public void testInsert(){
        long id = myService.addPerson( "JUNIT" );
        assertNotNull( id );
        if( id < 1 ){
            fail();
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that this test will fail because transaction was rollbacked, but the insert is OK!
If I remove `@TransactionConfiguration(defaultRollback=true)` then the test pass but a new record will be inserted into database.

```
@Test
@Transactional
@Rollback(true)
public void testInsert(){
    long id = myService.addPerson( "JUNIT" );
assertNotNull(id);
if( id < 1 ){
        fail();
    }
}
```

Now can test pass correctly, but rollback is ignored and the record is inserted into the database.
I have annotated the method `addPerson()` inside myService with `@Transactional`, obviously.
Why is the rollback being ignored?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You need to extend transaction boundaries to the boundaries of your test method. You can do it by annotating your test method (or the whole test class) as `@Transactional`:

```
@Test 
@Transactional
public void testInsert(){ 
    long id=myService.addPerson("JUNIT"); 
    assertNotNull(id); 
    if(id<1){ 
        fail(); 
    } 
}
```

You can also use this approach to ensure that data was correctly written before rollback:

```
@Autowired SessionFactory sf;

@Test 
@Transactional
public void testInsert(){ 
    myService.addPerson("JUNIT"); 
    sf.getCurrentSession().flush();
    sf.getCurrentSession().doWork( ... check database state ... ); 
}
```

Comment: hi, now test pass, but rollback was ignored. I have @Transactional over "testAddPerson" and over "addPerson".

Comment: If i remove @Transactional from myService, there is not an active transaction for the test, so i think @Transactional over "testAddPerson" doesn't work...

Comment: @blow: I just noticed that you have `extends AbstractJUnit38SpringContextTests`. It's not needed since you have a JUnit 4 test with `@RunWith`.

Comment: you are right. Without AbstractJUnit38SpringContextTests and AbstractTransactionalJUnit38SpringContextTests all works fine. Thank you.

Comment: i also had to add @TestExecutionListeners({TransactionalTestExecutionListener.class})

Answer (score 2):

check out

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/testing.html

Section 8.3.4 in particular

Spring has some classes for testing that will wrap each test in a transaction, so the DB is not changed.  You can change that functionality if you want too.

Edit -- based on your more infos, you  might want to look at

AbstractTransactionalJUnit38SpringContextTests at

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/test/context/junit38/AbstractTransactionalJUnit38SpringContextTests.html

Comment: thank you, this is useful, i found a little problem in my implementation. Now i have another problem, rollback is ignored

Answer (score 2):

Use Following annotation before class :

```
@TransactionConfiguration(transactionManager = "txManager",defaultRollback = true)
@Transactional
```

here `txManager` is application context's Transaction Manager.

Here `txManager` is an instance or bean id of Transaction manager from `application context`.

```
<!-- Transaction Manager -->
    <bean id="txManager"
          class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="txManager" />
```

Add your code inside `setUp()` method, this will execute in start of the test and the last wrap up code should be put in `teatDown()` method that will executed at last. or you can also use `@Before` and `@After` annotation instead of it.

Answer (score 0):

If your

```
myService.addPerson("JUNIT");
```

method is annotated like @Transactional you will be getting some different kind or errors trying to fix this. So you better just test DAO methods.