# junit test case for a method with hibernate fetch

Tags: java, hibernate, junit4

I have a `User` table and in `UserController.java` I have a method `userList();` which returns all users from database using hibernate.

How can I write a `JUnit` test case for this piece of code. I am new to JUnit`.

Please help.

```
public List<User> userList() {      
    try
    {       
          List <User> result =  hibernateTemplate.find("from User");        
          return result;
    }
    finally { 
        //close the session and user-supplied JDBC connection 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest using spring-test, I've always found it very useful while doing database testing.

Simply setup an in memory database or a clean database (no data) only for testing.

Connect to it and setup your test with the @Rollback spring annotation.

This instructs the framework to rollback all changes done in the test after its done. This works 90% of the time if your application has a normal transactional behavior, if not you might need to write an @After method that does the db clean up for you.

Just insert a couple of users, do your retrieve and assert that the retrieved users and equal in number and properties of those that you inserted.

Comment: Thanks. Any link for the implementation  will be appreciable.

Comment: Sure, this is one, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4166983/rollback-transaction-when-testing-service-with-spring-hibernate-junit check the answer marked as correct.