# Hibernate test does not finish

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa

I have a Java application with a connection to a MySQL database via Hibernate.

I have written a test for testing the connection to the database, but it never ends. Two threads are running, but all the code i've written in the test is executed. The two threads are:

```
Thread [pool-1-thread-1] (Running)  
Thread [DestroyJavaVM] (Running)
```

The following is my testfile:

```
Vote v1 = new Vote(0, "abc");
Vote v2 = new Vote(1, "def");
Candidate c1 = new Candidate(0, "First Candidate");
Timestamp t = new Timestamp(0, 123456l);

EntityManager entMgr = EntityManagerUtil.getEntityManagerFactory().createEntityManager();
EntityTransaction transaction = entMgr.getTransaction();
transaction.begin();

VoteRepository vr = new VoteRepository(entMgr);
entMgr.persist(v1);
entMgr.persist(v2);

CandidateRepository cr = new CandidateRepository(entMgr);
entMgr.persist(c1);

TimestampRepository tr = new TimestampRepository(entMgr);
entMgr.persist(t);

transaction.commit();
entMgr.close();
```

My persistence.xml looks like this:

```
<provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
    <!-- This is where we tell JPA/Hibernate about our @Entity objects -->
    <class>org.evoting.database.entities.Candidate</class>
    <class>org.evoting.database.entities.Timestamp</class>
    <class>org.evoting.database.entities.Vote</class>

<properties>
    <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://url" />
    <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="***" />
    <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="***" />
    <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect" />

    <!-- Update the database schema on startup: "update"; "validate" to only check -->
    <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />

    <!-- Echo all executed SQL to stdout -->
    <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />

    <!-- Disable the second-level cache -->
    <property name="hibernate.cache.provider_class" value="org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvicer" />

    <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" />
    <property name="hibernate.transaction.flush_before_completion" value="true" />
    <property name="hibernate.connection.autocommit" value="false" />
    <property name="hibernate.connection.release_mode" value="after_transaction" />
</properties>
```

What can cause the test to never finish?

Comment: Post the full code for the test method and class. Are you declaring the test to be transactional with a rollback. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4166983/how-to-rollback-a-database-transaction-when-testing-services-with-spring-in-juni

Comment: It is the complete code. It's just a plain old main method.

Comment: Try adding some System.out.println("test"); throughout your method so you can find out exactly which line execution is stopping.

Comment: The last line is executed, but the two threads are still running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out i had to close the EntityManagerFactory in order for the test to finish. So instead of

```
entMgr.close();
```

I should write

```
entMgr.getEntityManagerFactory.close();
```

With this new line the test finishes and everyone is happy :)