# Rollback transaction within test with Spring test

Tags: spring, testing

I'm trying to understand why I cannot rollback transaction if I throw exception in my test?

I'm using Spring 4.1.5 and I'm trying to test my transactions.
I've annotated @Transactional my repository and transaction have been
rolled back if repository throw exception. Also I've annotated
@Transactional my test method and calling several methods from
repository work in one transaction.
However when I trow exception in test by myself transaction is not rolled back. Why?
It looks like it was done by some purpose or do I do something wrong?

```
    @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
    @TransactionConfiguration(transactionManager = "transactionManager", defaultRollback = false)
    @ContextHierarchy({
            @ContextConfiguration(locations = {
                    "classpath:/META-INF/spring/jpa-persistence-context.xml"})
    })
    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, readOnly = false, rollbackFor = RuntimeException.class)
    public class FeaturedGroupRepositoryTest2 {

        @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, readOnly = false, rollbackFor = RuntimeException.class)
        @Test
        public void testFeaturedGroupDao() {

            FeaturedGroupEntity newFeaturedGroupEntity = new FeaturedGroupEntity();
            FeaturedGroupEntity savedFeaturedGroupEntity = featuredGroupRepository.save(newFeaturedGroupEntity);
            FeaturedGroupEntity foundFeaturedGroupEntity = featuredGroupRepository.findOne(savedFeaturedGroupEntity.getId());
            throw new RuntimeException("test rollback");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Possibly the same issue that @Kieren Dixon had in [How to rollback a database transaction when testing services with Spring in JUnit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4166983/how-to-rollback-a-database-transaction-when-testing-services-with-spring-in-juni) that you are missing the TransactionalTestExecutionListener annotation on your Junit class:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = TestConfiguration.class)
@TestExecutionListeners({TransactionalTestExecutionListener.class}) 
public class WorkUnitRepoTest {

    @Inject MyRepo repo;

    @Test
    public void test() {
        repo.delete(1);
    }
}
```

Even though the [Spring documentation for 4.1.7](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.1.7.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/) mentions that the listener is active by default, I had to add it manually to work. However the @Transactional is always required on either the class or method level for it to work.

Excerpt Spring Framework 4.1.7.RELEASE:

> In the TestContext framework, transactions are managed by the
>   TransactionalTestExecutionListener which is configured by default,
>   even if you do not explicitly declare @TestExecutionListeners on your
>   test class. To enable support for transactions, however, you must
>   configure a PlatformTransactionManager bean in the ApplicationContext
>   that is loaded via @ContextConfiguration semantics (further details
>   are provided below). In addition, you must declare Spring’s
>   @Transactional annotation either at the class or method level for your
>   tests.